# How to insert elements according to array of indices in MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector

Say, I have Index array I = [2 4 6]
Another, array A =[1 0 0]
I want to insert elements of array A in array C at position 2 , 4 and 6.

Array C is initially empty.

Run 2: I = [1, 7, 8]
A = [0 0 1]
I would want to insert elements of array A in array C at position 1 , 7 and 8.

And, so on.

Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: Something like this `C(I) = A`

Comment: What have you tried already? Have a read of [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#f1-85544), then try for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Cheery essentially answered the question for you, but in order to be complete, simply use the array `I` and index into `C` and use `I` to place the values of `A` into the corresponding slots in `C`.  As such:

```
C(I) = A;
```

If `C` was not already allocated, then `C` will pad whatever you didn't index with zeroes.  As such, given your two examples, this is what we get:

```
I1 = [2 4 6];
I2 = [1 7 8];
A1 = [1 0 0];
A2 = [0 0 1];
C1(I1) = A1
C2(I2) = A2


C1 =

     0     1     0     0     0     0   

C2 =

     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
```

However, because your array `A` already has zeroes, you can't really see the effect of this type of assignment.  If you change up your array `A` into some other values that don't include zero, then you'll see that this does work.